# Theorem related to Ore's Theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

I was trying to prove the above theorem. I could solve parts (a) and (b). But, I am stuck with part (c). Can someone provide some hints for part (c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a brief hint.

We can assume that vertices $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent (otherwise $P$ is a cycle).
Then all neighbors of $x$ lie in $P$, i.e. $N(x)\subset V(P)$ and similarly $N(y)\subset V(P)$ (otherwise there is a path longer than $P$).

It is clear that $|Y|=|N(y)|$ and $|X|=|N(x)|-1$.
Now consider two cases.

1. $X\cap Y\neq\emptyset$. In this case, $P$ is a cycle.
2. $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. Then $|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|=|N(x)|-1+|N(y)|\geq n-2$.
   Hence $|V(P)|=|V(G)|$ and $P$ is a spanning path.

Comment: Why is $|X| = |N(x)| -1$?

Comment: If $P=xv_1v_2\ldots v_ky$, $N(x)=\{v_1,v_{i_2},\ldots,v_{i_r}\}$, and $1<i_2<\ldots<i_r$, then $X=\{i_2-1,\ldots,i_r-1\}$